# How to change CSS from NPM package and use SCSS instead?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

So I downloaded a package from NPM its called react-csv-importer. My React app is using scss to customize layouts. I am coding from a react-bootstrap template I purchased from react-bootstrap.

Their layout is confusing me and I cant seem to understand how to customize an NPM package I install...

Here is a photo of the index.css file that contains everything I need to edit

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the layout of the SCSS

[image]

Here is another screenshot inside the theme folder, It contains most of the scss files

[image]

Now shouldnt I just be able to create a new file called something like csv-importer.scss and then copy the code from index.css thats located in the NPM package and update it in the SCSS? How do people go about editing an NPM install this way?

Answer (score 1):

You should never customize or touch a package you've installed through npm.  If you change the package in node_modules then 1. it will get overwritten as soon as you do npm install again, 2. it won't be saved to your github since you need to exclude node_modules with .gitignore.  node_module packages should be left alone, untouched.

Instead you should import the things you need to use from packages and use it in your own code.  So if you have a package called "example" that you've installed through npm then you need to do:

```
import Something from 'example'

// use Something here
```

In order to use it.  This is how you use stuff from node_modules.

In your case you should likely import the styles from the package you've installed, either through scss @import or through node import, after which you can use it in your own code.  However you should not modify the original code they have.

If the package they have is .css then you can't change that to .scss, you'll just have to use it as .css.  Which is not such a big deal since scss will get compiled to css anyways.

What you can do is to import all of their styles through @import and then to overwrite the things you want in your own code or scss.